Prove that $O_1$ moves along a fixed line as $A$ varies on arc $BC$.
This problem comes from my preparation for a mathematical Olympiad, and I am currently stuck on part (b). The problem is as follows:
Let $(\mathrm{O})$ be a circle with $O$, and $B$ and $C$ be two fixed points on the circle. Point $A$ moves on the major arc $BC$ such that triangle $\triangle ABC$ remains acute. Draw $AE \perp AC$ with $E \in BC$, and $AF \perp AB$ with $F \in BC$. Let $O_1$ be the circumcenter of triangle $\triangle AEF$.
Prove that:
(a) The three points $A, \mathrm{O}, O_1$ are collinear.
(b) As $A$ moves along the arc $BC$, the point $O_1$ moves along a fixed line.

I have successfully proved part (a), but I am struggling with part (b). My attempts so far include analyzing the geometric properties of the perpendiculars and using symmetry, but I couldn't make significant progress.
Any help or insight into solving part (b) would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Solution part a

Let $Ax$ be the tangent to the circumcircle of triangle $AEF$, and let $M$, $N$, $D$, and $G$ be the midpoints of $AF$, $AE$, $AC$, and $AB$, respectively. Since $Ax$ is a tangent, we have $\angle xAF = \angle AO_1M = \angle MNA$,
We also have, $\angle xAC=\angle xAF+\angle FAC= \angle ANG+\angle GAN=\angle AGD=\angle ABC$
which implies that $Ax$ is also the tangent to the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$. Hence, $A$, $O$, and $O_1$ are collinear

"A,O,O1 are collinear."  Please edit the question - how can a point and a circle be collinear?

show your efforts for part one to prevent down vote and vote to close the question.

It looks like the point $O_1$ is not moving along a fixed line. Please check.

@YNK that's a hyperbol line

@sirous i have modified, please help me reopen the question

Yes, Now I understand, The point $O_1$ moves along one branch of a fixed hyperbol. I voted for reopening you question.

In your proof of part($a$), you have successfully showed that the $Ax$ is a tangent to the smaller of the two circles shown in your diagram. But that circle is not the circumcircle of the $\triangle ABC$. To my understanding, you need to prove that $\measuredangle CBA = \measuredangle CAx$.

@YNK i have just modified, thank you

Any one help me, i have done anything to reopen my question, but it have not
